# Export external SVG file painted with Javascript to PNG image

Tags: javascript, html, svg, png

I am using an svg map from an external file.  I insert it to my html code using the "object" tag.

```
<object id="mymap" data="map.svg" width="884" height="760" type="image/svg+xml" ></object>
```

In javascript I paint paths of the svg map with some given colors. For example:

```
<script>
var path1 = document.getElementById('mymap').getSVGDocument().getElementById('path1');
path1.style.fill='#f00';

var path2 = document.getElementById('mymap').getSVGDocument().getElementById('path2');
path2.style.fill='#0f0';
</script>
```

How can I export the resulted coloured map as a PNG image?

**--UPDATE-- : The question has been answered, and the LiveExample now includes the solution for future reference.  You can view the source and get the solution.  The example draws a map and saves drawn map in a canvas that you can then save as file**

- [Example Solution Displaying the canvas](http://mobile.neakriti.gr/sandbox/svgmap/map.php)
- [Example Solution Hiding the canvas with direct download to generated image](http://mobile.neakriti.gr/sandbox/svgmap/map2.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about drawing the svg to the canvas, and then use the [`.toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL) to get as PNG image?

--Update--
For a quick test, i run the below in the console from your live demo:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var svgDoc = document.getElementById('mymap').getSVGDocument();
var svg = new Blob([svgDoc.lastChild.outerHTML], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var img = new Image(); 
img.onload = function(){ ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); };
img.src = url
```

you should see the url, which has the image draw, at this time just call the .toDataURL you should get the base64 image data

Comment: Can I draw to a canvas from an external file like I show in my initial post?

Comment: yes you can, for [quick example](http://getcontext.net/read/svg-images-on-a-html5-canvas)

Comment: it depends on how do you want to implement it. it also possible to take the object `#mymap` svg content and draw to the canvas

Comment: sorry i did a mistake yesterday.yes you got the idea right :) it should be `img.src = URL.createObjectURL(svg)` which create an objectUrl to `img.src`, and then it will trigger the onload function which draw the canvas. lastly only we call the `canvas.toDataURL("image/png")`...in order to trigger a download, u may call `window.location.href=canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream")` ...also another thing, the canvas size must be changed, default is 300x150. chage it with `canvas.width/heigth`, and also `img.onload = function(){ ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,884,760); };`

Comment: I finished the implementation.  On the Live Example in my initial question, I have it fully working.  Thank you for the help

Comment: u're welcome, they looks good @IoannisAnifantakis, but me myself still finding a way to trigger the save image (from the button, not the save as with right click) with the desired filename, no idea how to make it work :/

Comment: I beg to differ.  If you see at my solution I provide "download" canvas image with custom file name.  See the source

Comment: ya i saw that :) but im finding the way to trigger the download with just single click (draw to canvas, then get dataUrl, then immediately trigger the download

Comment: Call all the functions in "onLoad" and put the word "hidden" at the end of the canvas tag to hide it.  That way immediatelly you will get a download image from your interactive map the moment it loads without seeing the canvas.  I will update my initial question post with this functionality in a while...

Answer (score 1):

Solution is the following:
Based on my accepted solution I include the full javascript that manages all steps

Create a canvas

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid black;" width="884" height="760"></canvas>
```

Draw into that canvas the image from the painted svg

```
function drawCanvas(){
    // create a canvas and context
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    // define svgdocument and make blob containing its data
    var svgDoc = document.getElementById('mymap').getSVGDocument();
    var svg = new Blob([svgDoc.lastChild.outerHTML], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});


    // create a new image
    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg); 
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.onload = function(){ 
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,884,760); 
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

- [Example Solution Displaying the canvas](http://mobile.neakriti.gr/sandbox/svgmap/map.php)
- [Example Solution Hiding the canvas with direct download to generated image](http://mobile.neakriti.gr/sandbox/svgmap/map2.php)